# MINIX: Changing the chmod system call, printing acces rights

Tags: c, chmod, minix, access-rights

As part of a homework on minix operating system(version 3.2.1) I'm tasked with changing the chmod system call in the way that it prints the name and access rights right after I call it. For example the following command :

```
chmod 755 file.c
```

should have a printed message right after it like this :

```
chmod : file.c 755
```

I figured that I'll need to add/change code in the do_chmod function located in

> usr/src/servers/vfs/protect.c

I add the source code for this function below along with my changes:

```
/* This file deals with protection in the file system.It contains the code

* for four system calls that relate to protection.
 *

* The entry points into this file are
 *
   do_chmod:    perform the CHMOD and FCHMOD system calls
 *
   do_chown:    perform the CHOWN and FCHOWN system calls
 *
   do_umask:    perform the UMASK system call
 *
   do_access:   perform the ACCESS system call
 */


#include "fs.h"

#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <minix/callnr.h>

#include "file.h"

#include "fproc.h"

#include "path.h"

#include "param.h"

#include <minix/vfsif.h>

#include "vnode.h"

#include "vmnt.h"


/*===========================================================================*

*               do_chmod                     *

*===========================================================================*/

int do_chmod()

{

/* Perform the chmod(name, mode) and fchmod(fd, mode) system calls.

* syscall might provide 'name' embedded in the message.
 */


  struct filp *flp;

  struct vnode *vp;

  struct vmnt *vmp;

  int r, rfd;

  mode_t result_mode;

  char fullpath[PATH_MAX];

  struct lookup resolve;

  vir_bytes vname;

  size_t vname_length;

  mode_t new_mode;

/*int x;           --> THIS IS MY CODE

int y;             --> THIS IS MY CODE

int z;             --> THIS IS MY CODE */

  flp = NULL;

  vname = (vir_bytes) job_m_in.name;

  vname_length = (size_t) job_m_in.name_length;

  rfd = job_m_in.fd;

  new_mode = (mode_t) job_m_in.mode;


  lookup_init(&resolve, fullpath, PATH_NOFLAGS, &vmp, &vp);

  resolve.l_vmnt_lock = VMNT_READ;

  resolve.l_vnode_lock = VNODE_WRITE;


  if (job_call_nr == CHMOD) {

/* Temporarily open the file */

    if (copy_name(vname_length, fullpath) != OK) {

        /* Direct copy failed, try fetching from user space */

        if (fetch_name(vname, vname_length, fullpath) != OK)

            return(err_code);

    }

    if ((vp = eat_path(&resolve, fp)) == NULL) return(err_code);

  } else {
    /* call_nr == FCHMOD */

    /* File is already opened; get a pointer to vnode from filp. */

    if ((flp = get_filp(rfd, VNODE_WRITE)) == NULL) return(err_code);

    vp = flp->filp_vno;

    dup_vnode(vp);

  }


  /* Only the owner or the super_user may change the mode of a file.

* No one may change the mode of a file on a read-only file system.
   */

  if (vp->v_uid != fp->fp_effuid && fp->fp_effuid != SU_UID)

    r = EPERM;

  else
    r = read_only(vp);


  if (r == OK) {

    /* Now make the change. Clear setgid bit if file is not in caller's

* group */

    if (fp->fp_effuid != SU_UID && vp->v_gid != fp->fp_effgid)

        new_mode &= ~I_SET_GID_BIT;


    r = req_chmod(vp->v_fs_e, vp->v_inode_nr, new_mode, &result_mode);

    if (r == OK)

        vp->v_mode = result_mode;

  }


  if (job_call_nr == CHMOD)
 {

    unlock_vnode(vp);

    unlock_vmnt(vmp);

  }
 else { 
/* FCHMOD */

    unlock_filp(flp);

}

/*if(bits & S_IRUSR) x = x + 4;   --> THIS IS MY CODE

if(bits & S_IWUSR) x = x + 2;     --> THIS IS MY CODE

if(bits & S_IXUSR) x = x + 1;     --> THIS IS MY CODE

if(bits & S_IRWXG) y = y + 4;     --> THIS IS MY CODE

if(bits & S_IWGRP) y = y + 2;     --> THIS IS MY CODE

if(bits & S_IXGRP) y = y + 1;     --> THIS IS MY CODE

if(bits & S_IROTH) z = z + 4;     --> THIS IS MY CODE

if(bits & S_IWOTH) z = z + 2;     --> THIS IS MY CODE

if(bits & S_IXOTH) z = z + 1;     --> THIS IS MY CODE

printf("chmod: %s %d%d%d",fullpath,x,y,z);   --> THIS IS MY CODE */


  put_vnode(vp);

  return(r);

}
```

Now I've done a similar task in the mkdir system call where the objective was somewhat similar and these modifications worked. However during the compiling of the code it popped as an error that it couldn't recognize the bits variable. I don't know why's that an error since the file has included the sys/stat.h library. Any ideas?

Comment: where have you got "bits" variable from? Why don't you just 'printf("chmod: %s %o", fullpath, new_mode);'? PS: please, format your code correctly. (e.g. paste it when press the code button)

Comment: @Fat-Zer is correct, the first appearance of `bits` is when you try to use it, not declare/define it. However, I'm not sure printing `new_mode` is entirely correct since that's what you *tried* to change it to. You probably want to get the *actual* mode just in case it didn't work.

Comment: this seems to work thanks!I thought that bits&... was a global variable or something that I didn't need to define but guess I was wrong.. Furthermore how do you suggest I format my code? I copy/pasted it and pressed the sample code button. Is there anything more I should do?

Comment: @DimitrisDelis, about formatting, I'm actually not sure what went wrong with your paste, but there are empty lines and initial idents are missing — it's too spare and quite hard to read. It's not the first time I see it, but I can't reproduce it myself, so i can't tell what you are doing wrong (may be a browser/OS issue ?). This may worth asking on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).